# Operation to Find the Ratio Between Two Numbers $x,y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, notation, definition, absolute-value

**Background:** I'd like to find the fraction between two positive numbers $x,y$. By definition the fraction must be lower than or equal to one. So if $x>y$, I find $R(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}$, ad if $y>x$, $R(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$.

**Motivation:** It can be seen as the absolute value for ratios (in contrast to the absolute value for addition). It can also be seen as a metric or a distance defined by ratio.

**Question:** What operation is this $R$? Does it covered in any literature?

**Guess:** It is topologically equivalent to logarithm difference: $|\ln(x)-\ln(y)|$. This is a metric while $R$ is only a semimetric.

Does it have a name in literature so I can look it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed defined the equivalent for multiplication of absolute value for addition.

I know of no particular name for this function.

It defines the same topology as the absolute value of the difference of the logarithms. That might be a sensible way to measure "distance defined by ratio". Whether it's useful for you depends on the application.

Comment: Updated according to your answer. Sure, logarithm difference works too. Is this metric defined and used in literature? Does this metric has a name?

Comment: @HighGPA I can easily imagine that it's used somewhere. I don't know of a name for it.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are rational, $(x + y) / 2$ is rational and in between.

If they are irrational, you can try the following (here $\lceil z \rceil$ is the integer just larger than $z$, $\lfloor z \rfloor$ is the integer just smaller than $z$):

$\begin{align*}
  a
    &= \frac{1}{\lceil y - x \rceil} + 1 \\
  m
    &= \frac{\lceil a x \rceil + \lfloor a y \rfloor}{2 a}
\end{align*}$